# Issue with usbserial for arduino clone

Tags: serial, usb, mac-os

I have attached photo of the clone Uno board recently acquired, and I am working on a Mac OS X 10.7.5

I have sourced the solution from
http://javacolors.blogspot.com/2014/08/dccduino-usb-drivers-ch340-ch341-chipset.html

Which suggests to install 340/341CH drivers and run a sudo code. When I plug in the Uno board, the Arduino IDE still does not show under port selection, the "dev.tty.usbserial"

and as such I cannot contact or upload any command to the Uno board. Been trying for a whole day.. please help if you know a possible solution

This is the board:
[image: Uno board]

I bought the board from this site:

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/UNO-KIT-Upgraded-version-of-the-For-Starter-Kit-the-RFID-learn-Suite-Stepper-Motor-ULN2003/1207142899.html

screenshot from the IDE does now show any usbserial
[image: IDE screenshot]

Comment: It looks like the device node for a ch340 on a Mac should be of the form tty.wchusbserial### - at least that is what the screenshot is showing at http://www.codenuke.net/2015/01/nodemcu-install-ch340-usb-to-serial-for-yosemite.html

Answer (score 2):

You will need to allow the use of unverified drivers for this version of the Arduino. Unlike the genuine Arduino this board needs the ch340 and ch341 drivers and because they are not verified you will need to run the following command in order for them to work:

sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"

I just got a handful of these clones (so cheap) and once I installed the drivers and then set the nvram kernel extensions to dev mode all was OK.

Answer (score 0):

This may be better asked on http://apple.stackexchange.com

At the terminal run `ioreg -p IOUSB` then plug in the Arduino and see what changed.

On my Mac the setting is serial.port=/dev/tty.usbmodemfa131

Comment: A genuine UNO with an ATmega16u2 implement USB CDC will have a device node of that form, yes.  But that is not what the poster is connecting.  They are using something based on a ch340 chip instead.

Comment: @ChrisStratton and if the OP posted the ouyput of `ioreg -p IOUSB` we would know which chip.